# Strange symbol in overwatch

Tags: overwatch

I found a symbol on the left side of my screen in Overwatch. It looks like a lightning bolt with an arrow around it. Here is my sketch of it as I was unable to take a screenshot in time.[image: lightningboltwitharrow]

Can anyone tell me what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This icon pulses when your client hasn't heard from the server for a period longer than your interpolation delay. If this icon is consistently pulsing, it may indicate a connection problem, and can cause erratic behavior in game.

https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/37007 (Click on make a selection -> Network icons)

Basically, you are lagging.

Comment: No need to answer exact duplicates.

Comment: Answered before I realised it was a dupe.